# How to create named client after startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

For my application i need to make a named client for HttpRequests. I can create a named client in Startup. And to access it i inject an "**IHttpClientFactory**" and create a client from that. But the client needs to have an access token as an authorization header, and i cannot create the token in Startup. Therefor i need a way to create a named client outside of the Startup class. i have already tried injecting "**IServiceCollection**" into a controller. But this does not work.

Or is there maybe a way to edit a named client after it is already created in startup?

Comment: Where are you using the named client? Can't that service add the token?

Comment: `IServiceCollection` is the pre-build service registration tool. You want to inject `IServiceProvider`, although I don't see why this is necessary. Resolving dependencies in this way is something of an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar solution to the one posted by @Ruben-J is to create a custom HttpMessageHandler which assigns an authorization header to requests made through the HttpClient at request-time.

You can create a custom HttpMessageHandler that can be assigned to a named HttpClient in Startup like so:

```
public class YourHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IYourTokenProviderService _yourTokenProviderService;

    public YourHttpMessageHandler(IYourTokenProviderService yourTokenProviderService) 
        : base()
    {
        _yourTokenProviderService = yourTokenProviderService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = SendAsyncWithAuthToken(request, cancellationToken);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            await _yourTokenProviderService.RefreshTokenAsync();

            response = SendAsyncWithAuthToken(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        return response;
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendWithAuthTokenAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _yourTokenProviderService.Token);

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You then configure your services and named HttpClient in Startup:

```cs
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    ...
    services.AddTransient<IYourTokenProviderService, YourTokenProviderService>();
    services.AddTransient<YourHttpMessageHandler>();

    services.AddHttpClient<IYourNamedHttpClient, YourNamedHttpClient>()
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<YourHttpMessageHandler>();
    ...
}
```

Its worth noting that the current implementation of Polly's `AddPolicyHandler` is also adding its own DelegatingHandler.
For more background see the Microsoft [documentation on adding DelegatingHandler's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#outgoing-request-middleware). [Here is also great series of articles from Steve Gordon](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Polly to add a policy handler to your client. You can then add logic  if a request returns a 401 Unauthorized. So for example get your service that uses the client to refresh a bearer token and also set it for the current request. This is just a quick solution and maybe there are more elegant solutions. But this will also come in handy if your token expires. Cause then it will be refreshed automatically.

```
services.AddHttpClient("YourClient")
            .AddPolicyHandler((provider, request) =>
            {
                return Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    .RetryAsync(1, async (response, retryCount, context) =>
                    {
                        var service = provider.GetRequiredService<IYourService>();
                        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",  await service.RefreshToken());
                    });
            });
```

Comment: Thank you thats very helpfull. Let's say that when the HttpStatusCode is "OK". Would i be able to add a new HttpClient with the response? Like instead of doing RetryAsync i would just create a new HttpClient and get the access token from the response.

Comment: I would use the same httpclient you already have injected in your service. And let that call another url to get the new token. No need for creating another httpclient.